# Use of どうか in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm having some trouble parsing this sentence:

> ピーターのことを、どうかよろしくお願いします

The translation by my interpretation is something along the lines of "As to Peter I will leave it in your hands" (i.e. I will let you take care of Peter). However I am confused at what the precise role of どうか is in this sentence.

Comment: どうかusually translates as "please".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semantically there's no difference between with and without どうか in your phrase. As @Eddie Kal correctly points out in the comment, どうか just makes it more polite.

Examples:

- どうか助けてください。
- どうか行かないでください。

Do not mix it up with どうかする, which means something like "to become crazy".